# Interface for default funtion arguments and extend interface

Tags: typescript

I got *n* very similar functions, here is example:

```
  const functionOne = (firstName: string, lastName: string) => `${lastName}, ${firstName}`;
  const functionTwo = (firstName: string, lastName: string) => `${firstName} - ${lastName}`;
  const functionThree = (firstName: string, lastName: string, age: number) =>
    `${firstName}: ${lastName}, ${age}`;
```

As you can see all three of them has same duplicated code: `firstName: string; lastName: string;`

I was hoping if it's possible to use one interface for all functions and then extended if needed.

Something like this:

```
  interface IArguments {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
  }

  const functionOne = (IArguments) => `${lastName}, ${firstName}`;
  const functionTwo = (IArguments) => `${firstName} - ${lastName}`;
  const functionThree = ({ age: number } extends IArguments) =>
    `${firstName}: ${lastName}, ${age}`;
```

Which sadly doesn't work.

**Edit:**

I also want don't want to wrap arguments in object.

I want to be able to call functions like so:

```
funtionOne("James", "Brown");
```

Comment: Why do you want "interface for arguments" instead of making using an interface for an object and passing such an object?

Comment: @VLAZ I want to be able to do `funtionOne("James", "Brown")` and not `funtionOne({ firstName: "James", lastName: "Brown" })`

Comment: The question is *why*? Re-using arguments for a function is VERY rare and when it shows up, you usually want an object parameter anyway because now you're describing a known unit of data, not a disparate collection of values.

Comment: just because it's shorter, in my particular case there 8 functions 6 of which only take two values and 2 other same two values and `options` object

Comment: You could create a function interface where `type A = (firstName: string, lastName: string) => string` and `type B = (firstName: string, lastName: string, age:number) => string` which means you can do `functionOne: A`, `functionTwo: A`, and `functionThree:B`. I'm not sure if this helps that much. Or you can model this as a tuple and use rest parameters to compact these into a tuple, but then you need to unpack them. I'm not a fan of either, as it really seems you need an object parameter, not a short term fix.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, I tried to do what you said but end up with even more messy code, I guess I will just stick with what I have.